# Creating dataframe similar to the index and match functions in excel

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Short example of what I am trying to accomplish:
df1 with col1 = 'All_stocks' and col2 = 'earnings'
df2 with col1 = 'Stock_tix' 
I would like col 2 in df2 to equal the earnings from df1 based on the 'stock tickers' i have in df2 col1

df1 =

```
All_stocks    Earnings   
AAPL          50
TSLA          43
RNR           39
FB            90
```

df2 =

```
Stock_tix
AAPL
TSLA
```

so I am trying to figure out the code to make df2 look as follows based on what I have above:

df2 =

```
Stock_tix    Earnings
AAPL         50
TSLA         43
```

I have tried iterating through the data frame, .loc  .ix etc and nothing seems to work like a simple match and index did in excel.  I am pretty knew to python and this is my first post on Stackoverflow so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is nice, but better is add your code. If doesnt work, no problem.  You can check [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey thanks!  I will check that out tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for deleting column `All_stocks`:

```
print pd.merge(df2,df1, left_on='Stock_tix', right_on='All_stocks').drop('All_stocks',axis=1)
  Stock_tix  Earnings
0      AAPL        50
1      TSLA        43
```

Comment: It took a little bit of tweaking but the merge function was just what i needed for this to work.